# C# Expression, transform and combine an expression

Tags: c#, expression

I have a method like this :

```
public static Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<byte>>> GetSerializer(Expression<Func<T, int>> expr)
{
    return m => BitConverter.GetBytes();
}
```

`T` is a class with different member type : `int`, `string`, `bool` or custom classes.
I would like to know if it is possible in this method to make an `expression` where I serialize the `int` variable from parameters to `byte[]` and return it.
My goal is to execute this code later.

It is only theorical, I don't want to serialize an int, just trying to understand how `Expressions` work.

Comment: In your code, `T` is not necessarily a `class`. Looks like it can be a `struct` too. If you assume any constraint, do it explicitly with `where`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make expression that invokes other expression, you should build it dynamically.
Example:

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<byte>>> GetSerializer<T>(Expression<Func<T, int>> expr)
    {
        // Find GetBytes method which accepts int as an argument
        var method = typeof(BitConverter).GetMethod("GetBytes", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null,
            CallingConventions.Any, new[] {typeof(int)}, null);

        // Input parameter for lambda -> (T p)
        var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        // Body of lambda -> BitConverter.GetBytes(expr(p))
        var body = Expression.Call(method, Expression.Invoke(expr, p));

        // Build lambda -> (T p) => BitConverter.GetBytes(expr(p))
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, IEnumerable<byte>>>(body, p);
    }
```

Note that it looks up for `GetBytes` method during runtime, so even if method `BitConverter.GetBytes(int)` doesn't exist it will compile.

You can go even further and make this method fully generic:

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<byte>>> GetSerializer<T, T2>(Expression<Func<T, T2>> expr)
        where T2 : struct
    {
        // Find GetBytes method which accepts T2 as an argument
        var method = typeof(BitConverter).GetMethod("GetBytes", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null,
            CallingConventions.Any, new[] {typeof(T2)}, null);

        // Check if method exists
        if (method == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid type provided");
        }

        // Input parameter for lambda -> (T p)
        var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        // Body of lambda -> BitConverter.GetBytes(expr(p))
        var body = Expression.Call(method, Expression.Invoke(expr, p));

        // Build lambda -> (T p) => BitConverter.GetBytes(expr(p))
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, IEnumerable<byte>>>(body, p);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I try asap !